# How can I get get values outside this while loop in JSP?

Tags: jsp, loops, while-loop

How can I get get values outside this while loop in JSP.
 The code is as follows:

```
<%stat3=conn.createStatement();
rsobj=stat3.executeQuery(query1);
while(rsobj.next()) {
    int charge = Integer.parseInt(rsobj.getString(4));
    rate1=charge+rate1; %>    
    <tr>  
    <td  class="label" colspan="3" align="left">Net Amount Payable</td>
    <td class="database"  align="left"><%=rate1%></td>
</tr>
<tr>  
    <td  class="label" colspan="3" align="left">Due Amount</td>
    <td class="database"  align="left"><%=rsobj.getString(6)%></td>
</tr>
<%}%>
```

As this is a while loop but I want only rate1 i.e. total sum of amount to display in my program. I am not getting how could i do this. The above code displays all the values in the loop.

Comment: Can you rephrase it to be more clear? I'm having a hard time figuring out what you're asking. Do you want to compute rate in the while loop and afterwords format that rate into the table? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Just print that row only when the loop is finished?

```
<%stat3=conn.createStatement();
rsobj=stat3.executeQuery(query1);
while(rsobj.next()) {
    int charge = Integer.parseInt(rsobj.getString(4));
    rate1=charge+rate1; %>    
<tr>  
    <td  class="label" colspan="3" align="left">Due Amount</td>
    <td class="database"  align="left"><%=rsobj.getString(6)%></td>
</tr>
<%}%>
<tr>  
    <td  class="label" colspan="3" align="left">Net Amount Payable</td>
    <td class="database"  align="left"><%=rate1%></td>
</tr>
```

Needless to say that doing the DB access inside a JSP is a pretty terrible design approach.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I access my DB rather in JSP? Can you please guide me for that?